# Intellij IDEA Image comments plugin?

Tags: plugins, comments, javadoc

I've need of plugin for IDEA which allows link or attach images (prefferably, svg) to java/xml code comments (because my project is case when one picture is worth thousand words)..

So, is there such plugin available? And if there is't, is it hard to implement such plugin by myself?

Comment: Don't know of such a thing.  Why not just use the @link javadoc attribute?  Don't know if you could write such a thing; only you can answer that.  http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/03/plugin-development-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: Good idea. Feature request to embed images into Java Source Code in IntellijIDEA: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220975?_ga=2.190389481.353579935.1637842015-1537167577.1561966030